# Laravel авторизация пользователя после регистрации

Tags: laravel

Как запретить авторизацию пользователя после регистрации ?
После регистрации перекинуть на определённую страницу

Comment: как бы есть middleware прям в laravel есть RedirectIfAuthenticated которая перекидывает при авторизации  в котором редиректит на /home через константу из RouterServiceProvider::HOME, вашу поведенческую модель вы можете реализовать как угодно, но как бы посмотреть в сторону готовой реализации и понять ее можно было бы. В контролере регистрации тоже можно переопределить функцию registered а значит и в нее можно что-то наипсть. В общем я как минимум 2 варианта только что описал. Решайте как вам удобнее.

Comment: https://laraveldaily.com/9-things-you-can-customize-in-laravel-registration/

4 пункт

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, то нужно переопределить метод регистрации в `RegisterController`, что бы после регистрации пользователь не авторизовался автоматически

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($this->create($request->all())));

    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```